# Trigger Click Event after going to other page Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, events, click, load

by clicking a link I am going to index page's specific from a diffrent page, and on the same link I am performing a jquery click event, Although I am going to index pages's section but unable to trigger that click event after index page loaded, is there is way to perform both functions.

I want to go to index page and the open link-related tab.

```js
$(".footer-links li a").on("click", function(e) {
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  $("#" + id).prop("checked", true);
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
  }, 500);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="footer-links">
  <li>Services</li>
  <li><a href="index.html#specialities-tabs">Brand Management</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html#specialities-tabs" data-id="tab-2">In & Outdoor Signage</a></label>
  </li>
  <li><a href="index.html#specialities-tabs" data-id="tab-3">Large Format Printing</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html#specialities-tabs" data-id="tab-4">Exhibition Stands</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html#specialities-tabs" data-id="tab-5">Interior Fit Outs</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You cannot trigger an event on another page. If the link brings the User to a new section of the same page, the Script will still be available. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have converted your code parts into a snippet.